# get-azconsumptiondetails won't work for some resources

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, azure-billing-api, azure-billing

I'm using get-azconsumptionusagedetails in Powershell to get consumption of all of the resources for azure sponsorship acc, but for some of the resources it won't show anything (no error either), even though they are in the same RG as the ones that work.

Does anyone know the reason behind it?

I'm using

```html
Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -InstanceName $r.Name
```

Comment: It is not recognizing the name $r.Name.

Answer (score 0):

> get-azconsumptiondetails won't work for some resources

I tried to fetch the resource usage details using `Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail` cmdlet but it's not working properly and same is already reported in [Github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/21724)

Alternatively, you can check the Azure resource cost usage details in Azure CLI command.

```
$r = az consumption usage list | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($usageDetail in $r) {
    $instanceName = $usageDetail.instanceName
    $pretaxCost = $usageDetail.pretaxCost
    $usageQuantity = $usageDetail.usageQuantity
    $usageStart = $usageDetail.usageStart
    $usageEnd = $usageDetail.usageEnd
    
    Write-Host "Instance Name: $instanceName"
    Write-Host "Pretax Cost: $pretaxCost"
    Write-Host "Usage Quantity: $usageQuantity"
    Write-Host "Usage Start: $usageStart"
    Write-Host "Usage End: $usageEnd"
    Write-Host "=================================="
}
```

Output:

[image]

Reference:  [az consumption usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/consumption/usage?view=azure-cli-latest)